# Is transactions in bitcoin blockchain always coin transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, blockexplorer

I'm new to crypto currencies correct me if I am wrong, when I checked the block explorer I found a single block contains nearly 2300 transaction in it and I think at an average every 10 minutes a new block is created. **My question is, Is all the transaction in the block is, one sending bitcoins to some other or Is there any other application running in bitcoin block chain like in etherium.** Because with this much of demand in bitcoin and that many transactions happening even inside 10 minutes is quite unbelievable (sometimes this question might sound stupid).

Answer (score 2):

All transactions are "sending bitcoins to somewhere".

Some of these transactions are "sending bitcoins to nowhere". Some others are "sending bitcoins to the same place". And some transactions are "sending zero bitcoins to somewhere"

So, there are no other data structures in bitcoin blockchain except of moving bitcoins from one place to another. But the transactions can handle portions of arbitrary data.

Comment: "sending zero bitcoins to somewhere" will be a non-standard transaction. It is interesting to find out whether this was possible in satoshi's first version. edit: found https://blockchain.info/tx/b4ea693a9d2d7e32b66777964fce13da302bed024bd9fd4651919da650fb1c40

Comment: hehe :) this tx was created by me :)